# Determine if the series converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm not sure where to start/ which method to use for this series.$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos n}{n^3}$$
Any help would be great thanks!

Comment: Goes down fast enough. Converges absolutely, Compare absolute values with $\frac{1}{n^3}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$\Bigl |\frac{\cos(n)}{n^3}\Bigr| \le \frac{1}{n^3}$$
Now use the comparison test.

Comment: @mookid when dealing with sine and cosine, taking absolute value and saying that $|\cos x| \leq 1$ is a very very common technique. David congratulations on 5k rep

Comment: @user92774, thanks!  Should just explain - mookid was not questioning the answer, it was a comment about the typesetting and I deleted my comment when it was no longer relevant.

Comment: I just edited your post to fix an issue which caused your answer to disappear.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the $p$-series comparison test. $\cos(n) \leq 1$, so you can bound it above by $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n^{3}}$.