# Does the series converge or diverge as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(n)}{n^3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

It is pretty obvious that it converges, seeing as $n^3$ continues getting larger, and $\cos(n)$ is bounded by $1$ and $-1$.

The ratio and root tests are useless. I was just wondering if I could use the alternating series test even though:

1. there is no $(-1)^n$ in the function,
2. $\cos(n)$ does not alternate signs for each $\ n+1$.

I don't know how else I would solve this.

Edit: Or, could I compare it to $\frac1{n^3}$?

Comment: Just use the squeeze theorem

Comment: Use Comparison to prove absolute convergence, from which convergence follows.

Comment: See [this question asked yesterday](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717371)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $|\cos x| \leq 1$ for all real $x$, we see that
$$ \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \left|\frac{\cos n}{n^3}\right| \leq \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3}.$$
But the right-hand side converges because it is a convergent $p$-series, so $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty (\cos n)/n^3$ converges by the comparison test. Since the series has absolute convergence, it is also convergent (absolute convergence is stronger than convergence).